# Blogger: how to create custom Variable definitions for the Designer page

Tags: xml, variables, blogger, blogspot

When you login to Blogger.com and click the Template page, one of the first things you see in every template is "Variable definitions". These variable definitions show up on the user-friendly Designer page of the Blogger.com interface.

For example:

```
<Group description="Blog Title" selector=".header h1">
<Variable name="header.font" description="Title Font" type="font" default="normal bold 40px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal bold 40px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif"/>
<Variable name="header.text.color" description="Title Color" type="color" default="$(body.text.color)"  value="#000000"/>
<Variable name="header.background.color" description="Header Background" type="color" default="transparent"  value="transparent"/>
</Group>
```

The above variable definition lets you easily change the color of the blog title and other header information.

I would like to create my own custom variables.

I understand how most of the variables work. Like "name=" is the variable to use in the class or ID CSS. Like if the name is name="custom.name.here" then it should associate with the class name or ID that you want to change. Hence:

```
#Header1 {
$(custom.name.here)
}
```

"description=" is the name that will show up on the Designer page, so you know what you're changing.

The only parts in questions are: the "type=" variables and options that can be placed in the "type="? And also "default=" and "value=" what are these and what can be placed in these? Are these needed?

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post](http://www.bloggerguide.lk/2008/05/template-variables.html) has a good explanation of the variables. In summary the attributes of a variable are as follows.

- name - Unique id of the variable. Cannot contain spaces.
- description: A short description that shows up on the designer page.
- type: The type of the variable. 3 allowed types are `color`, `font` and `automatic`
- default: The template default value. This value gets applied whenever "Revert to template default" option is choosen.
- value: The current value of the variable.

Comment: Link is dead. Otherwise helpful.

Comment: Seems the site is down. You can use this archive link http://web.archive.org/web/20131021000907/http://www.bloggerguide.lk/2008/05/template-variables.html

Comment: A thing that I'd like to understand, is the use of the variable in the template editor, in sections called "groups". What are the rules if I want to create a custom variable, that will be shown properly and customizable directly in the template editor? (and displayed in the proper group)

Comment: Thank you for the archive link, @Nufail! Shouldn't the original message be edited to include this link instead of the dead one? I've found this one, that seems to mirror the content of the archive. http://bguide.blogspot.com/2008/05/template-variables.html

Comment: Note: The page seems a bit outdated, because I think there are more custom variables types than only Color, Font and Automatic. I see "length" for instance. I didn't find a good tutorial